# Check to see if all top-level objects have identical properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is some JSON:

```
{
  "environments":{

    "production":{
      "zmq_config":{
        "host":"*",
        "port":"7676"
      },
      "redis_server_config":{
        "host":"localhost",
        "port":"26379"
      }
    },

    "dev_remote":{
      "zmq_config":{
        "host":"*",
        "port":"5555"
      },
      "redis_server_config":{
        "host":"localhost",
        "port":"16379"
      }
    },

    "dev_local":{
      "zmq_config":{
        "host":"*",
        "port":"5555"
      },
      "redis_server_config":{
        "host":"localhost",
        "port":"6379"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a test in my test suite that ensures all of the properties have the same properties of their complements.

For example, for each property of "environments", I want to check that they have the same properties; in this case they do - they all have 2 properties "zmq_config" and "redis_server_config". Now I want to do at least one more level of checking. For properties "zmq_config" and "redis_server_config", I want to check that they in turn have the same properties "host" and "port".

You get the idea.

Is there a library that can do this? Is there some sort of JavaScript identity operator that check for this, just looking at the top level objects?

Now the easiest way I can think of doing this is simply to iterate through and look at each property with the same name (making the assumption that properties with the same name are in the same place in the object hierarchy), and then simply seeing if they have the same subproperties.

Is `Underscore.js` the best option? It seems Underscore has this functionality which might work:

```
_.isEqual(obj1, obj2);
```

from my research it looks like this is the best candidate:

```
_.isMatch(obj1,obj2);
```

Comment: Have a look at underscore. It has some shallow comparison stuff that might work.

Comment: Do you want to check for those properties specifically, or just that whatever properties one object has, the others have the same?

Comment: I just want to check property keys not property values, making sure the name of the keys is the same, so yes, the latter.

Answer (score 1):

For each object to test, you can use Object.keys function to extract the keys of the object and then compare them, because you only want to know if properties are equals, the value not matters.

Then, when you extract the keys of each object, you can compare using _.isEqual function by provided by lodash instead of underscore (usually lodash has better performance).

To automate as possible, you should create a recursive function to extract the keys and compare them.

Comment: `_.isEqual(['foo','bar'], ['bar','foo']) // false`

Comment: You are right @Moogs but usually, if you have a json like you expose, is generated for a backend and "columns" or "attributes" will be at the same order. In any case you could sort the array with native js function sort: `_.isEqual(['foo','bar'].sort(), ['bar','foo'].sort())`

Answer (score 1):

Hacked this real quick but it should do you justice. It returns true if all nested object keys match. At each level it checks if the array of keys matches the other object's array of keys and it does that recursively.

function keysMatch(data1, data2) {
    var result = null;

```
function check(d1, d2) {
    if (result === false) {
        return false;
    }
    if (_.isObject(d1) && _.isObject(d2)) {
        if (allArraysAlike([_.keys(d1), _.keys(d2)])) {
            result = true;
            _.forOwn(d1, function (val, key) {
                check(d1[key], d2[key]);
            });
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
  }

  return check(data1, data2);
}

function allArraysAlike(arrays) {
    return _.all(arrays, function (array) {
        return array.length == arrays[0].length && _.difference(array, arrays[0]).length == 0;
    });
}

console.log(keysMatch(json1, json2));
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/baafbjo8/2/**

Comment: Embedding *check* as a separate function insid *keysMatch* isn't a good strategy in this case. You're just adding the overhead of an extra function call (which is relatively expensive) for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple true/false answer, then a simple function can be created from basic javascript.

The function below uses ES5 features, but wouldn't be much more code using plain loops (and run a bit fast to boot, not that it's slow).

```
/**
 *  @param {Object} obj - Object to check properties of
 *  @param {Array} props - Array of properties to check
 *  @returns {boolean}
**/
function checkProps(obj, props) {
  // List of members of obj
  var memberNames  = Object.keys(obj);
  // Use keys of first object as base set
  var baseKeys = Object.keys(obj[memberNames[0]]);

  // Check every object in obj has base set of properties
  // And each sub-object has props properties
  return memberNames.every(function (memberName) {

    // Get member
    var member = obj[memberName];

    // Get keys of this member
    var memberKeys = Object.keys(member);

    // First check that member has same keys as base, then that each sub-member
    // has required properties
    return memberKeys.length == baseKeys.length &&
           baseKeys.every(function(key) {
             return member.hasOwnProperty(key) &&

                    // Check sub-member properties
                    props.every(function(prop) {
                      return member[key].hasOwnProperty(prop);
                    });
           });
  });
}

console.log(checkProps(env,['host','port']));
```

For EcmaScript ed 4 compatability, requires polyfills for [*Array.prototype.every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill) and [*Object.keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill).